# A MAC based communications between laptops using Java

Tags: java, networking, network-protocols

Greetings fellow programmers,

This will be a long question so bear with me.

I am doing a project in University and my part is basically focused on communications between laptops computers through wireless lan. Language I am using is Java. This communication should not require any laptop to connect another in a direct basis. So lets assume I have created an access point on one computer, others should not directly connect to it and get IP address' and then simply connect via IP sockets.

Thus, what remains as an option is to connect via MAC address'. What I have thought of so far is to relay, say for an example, my MAC address, IP address through wlan adapter. From my previous networking class I thought of sending these informations to broadcast channel of MAC address so that any laptop with wlan open would get it. Then if I saved these information in a database, whenever I needed, I could extract MAC address and IP address from the database, relay the information I want to send to a specific MAC address instead of broadcast address (thus only a specific MAC address could get it and other machines in the coverage area could not get it).

I thought, this way to communicate between computers would prove to be very useful and we wouldn't need any socket programming at all. By the way, in the program security is not a concern thus direct relaying of MAC address, IP address etc. is not considered as an issue. I have made a lot of research about this concept past two weeks but I was not successful at all. What I have read so far is that, Java is not able to work below Layer 3 in networking. However, there are some external libraries that help Java work with Layer 2 from what I have read so far but I was not able to make them work in my computer somehow. My teacher suggested me to create my own small protocol but thus far I couldn't figure out how to order wlan adapter to send a broadcast message.

My questions are,

(1) Is there actually a way to order wlan adapter to send specific messages to specific MAC address in Java such as ARP.

(2) Are there any useful Java libraries that help with any of this? Such as, creating custom ARP packets (with the information I want to send in them) or alike that might give me an edge in Layer 2 networking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are doing. ARP is enabled by default (you can disable it with the ifconfig command), and you can read and write the kernel's ARP table using ioctls like SIOCGARP to read the ARP table and send an ARP if necessary, and SIOCSARP to set an ARP table entries (of course, Java can't use that directly, you'll need JNI or an easier native library like JNA or Bridj).

If you really need to create your own Ethernet/IP/ARP/other low-level networking packets, look at https://code.google.com/p/netutils/

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit to using level-2 networking directly, people have put a lot of work into making IP work very well. Some disadvantages of using layer-2 are that you need to be root and it's non-portable. It's also not directly possible in Java, you'd need to write/use an extension written in C.

If you want to send a message to a single machine, send a UDP packet to its IP address. If you want to send a message to many machines (all, or some sub-group) then send a UDP packet to a multicast group and have the receiving machines join that group.